# QR code webcam scanner c#

Tags: c#, webcam, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I Have tried various *QR code* libraries and *webcam capturing* techniques. Capturing photos within a specific time interval and then sending it to the *QR code* library seemed as a good idea but the success ratio for detecting the *QR code* is extremely low. Could anyone recommend a better approach for detecting the *QR code* through webcam? Thanks a lot :)

Code:

void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

```
        Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

        pictureBox1.Image = video;
        try
        {
            com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.Decoder objDecoder = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.Decoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap, bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height); 
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            QRCodeReader qrCodeReader = new QRCodeReader();
            string str = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binBitmap).Text;
            MessageBox.Show(str);

        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

}

I also used messaging.toolkit.qrcode.dll.
The code follows:

private void mainWinForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

        webcam = new WebCam();
        webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref imgVideo);
        QRCodeDecoder decoder = new QRCodeDecoder();
        try
        {

            MessageBox.Show(decoder.decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(imgCapture.Image as Bitmap)));
        }

        catch
        {
            //Do nothing
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code you've already created.

Comment: Both the above codes keep giving me decoder failed exception

Comment: Any help would be great

Comment: Did u get any solution man? i too have a same problem though i have no idea about implementing which dll , if u had done pls share me the details...

Answer (score 5):

Try using AForge.NET library for capturing the video from your webcam, and then ZXing.Net library for reading the QR codes.

You can follow some Youtube tutorials like these that will show how to get video from the webcam using AForge.Net . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osAOpsRYqVs&t=311s

As for the QRs decoding I used the following code which I execute every 1 second:

`

```
    private void decode_QRtag()
    {
        try
        {
            //pictureBox1 shows the web cam video
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

            BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader { AutoRotate = true, TryHarder = true };
            Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
            string decoded = result.ToString().Trim();        
            //capture a snapshot if there is a match
            PictureBox2.Image = bitmap;
            textBox1.Text = decoded;
        }
        catch 
        {
        }
    }`
```

Comment: For those of you trying to get this code under .NET core running (it will not), see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76335212/1202211)

Answer (score 2):

```
**For this you should install these packages
Install-Package AForge
Install-Package AForge.Video
Install-Package AForge.Video.DirectShow
Install-Package ZXing.Net

you can watch this video for more help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcoy0Gwxr50**




    using System.IO;
    using AForge;
    using AForge.Video;
    using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
    using ZXing;
    using ZXing.Aztec;


      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
                foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
                }

                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                FinalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
                FinalFrame.Start();

            }

            private void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            }

            private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BarcodeReader Reader = new BarcodeReader();
                Result result = Reader.Decode((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
                try
                {
                    string decoded = result.ToString().Trim();
                    if (decoded != "")
                    {
                        timer1.Stop();
                        MessageBox.Show(decoded);
                        Form2 form = new Form2();
                        form.Show();
                        this.Hide();

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Start();
            }

            private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {
                if (FinalFrame.IsRunning == true)
                {
                    FinalFrame.Stop();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wanted working copy and paste code here just make sure you made a form and installed the Packages listed here

```
Install-Package AForge
Install-Package AForge.Video
Install-Package AForge.Video.DirectShow
Install-Package ZXing.Net
```

Code to copy and paste

```
using System.IO;
using AForge;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.Aztec;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace QR_Reader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection CaptureDevice;
        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalFrame;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
            }

            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            FinalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
            FinalFrame.Start();
        }
        private void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Scanner Strated");
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalFrame.IsRunning == true)
            {
                FinalFrame.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BarcodeReader Reader = new BarcodeReader();
            Result result = Reader.Decode((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
            try
            {
                if(result == null) { return; }
                string decoded = result.ToString().Trim();
                Console.WriteLine(decoded);
                if (decoded != "")
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show(decoded);
                    //Form2 form = new Form2();
                    //form.Show();
                    //this.Hide();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add these Components listed below to the form

```
Timer
CompoundBox
PictureBox
Button1
Button2
```

Button is to show cam
Button 2 is to start scanning

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your code makes me easy life.

Works excelent, I added a 3rd button for automatic scan every 2 seconds.

```
 private void BtnEscaneoAuto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     timer1.Stop();
     timer1.Interval = 2000;
     timer1.Enabled = true;
     timer1.Start();
     EscaneoAuto = true;
     textBox1.Text = "Escaneo Automático Iniciado..." + Environment.NewLine;
 }
```

And I modified a tick event

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     BarcodeReader Reader = new BarcodeReader();
     Result result = Reader.Decode((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
     try
     {
         if (result == null) { return; }
         string decoded = result.ToString().Trim();
         Console.WriteLine(decoded);
         if (decoded != "")
         {
             if (EscaneoAuto)
             {
                 textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + decoded + Environment.NewLine;
             }
             else
             {
                 timer1.Stop();
                 MessageBox.Show(decoded);
             }                    
             //Form2 form = new Form2();
             //form.Show();
             //this.Hide();

         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
 }
```

regards.

Comment: If someone has helped you, please accept their answer with the tick button on the right side of the answer.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35691981)